# Apache mod-rewrite for shorter urls

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

Is it possible do do something like this with mod-rewrite?

Current url:

```
www.example.com/Departments/dynamicPage.php?DeptID=10&DeptName=HR
```

to set up a rewrite so:

```
www.example.com/hr
```

could redirect to the above (with the arguments)?

I know I could create an "hr" folder on the root level and put in an html page with a meta refresh, but I hate the extra clutter.

I don't think a .htaccess 301 is possible, but please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm looking for an elegant solution that can be added to for future instances.

Comment: The mod-rewrite directives below will work in an .htaccess file as long as you have "AllowOverride FileInfo" set on the directory in your Apache configuration: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Answer (score 2):

Seems reasonable. Something along the lines of this should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^hr$ /Departments/dynamicPage.php?DeptID=10&DeptName=HR [L]
```

If you want to make it generic:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /Departments/dynamicPage.php?DeptID=10&DeptName=$1 [L]
```

Of course, then you need to be careful about people heading to departments which don't actually exist, and you'll need to make sure all your DeptNames make sense.

If you want a 301 redirect, use `[R=301]` or `[L,R=301]` at the end of the rewrite rule.

Comment: The generic solution may not work correctly because you have DeptID=10 in the URL.

Comment: Good point. The problem there is more one of redundant information. That could probably be ditched altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^hr$ Departments/dynamicPage.php?DeptID=10&DeptName=HR [R=301]
```

Comment: does the ^hr$ specify this is off the root like ...com/hr/ or would it also redirect if there was another nested directory like ..com/this/that/theother/hr/
???

Comment: `^` at the beginning of a regular expression requires the following sequence to match the start of the string (in our case, the URL). `$` at the end of a regular expression requires the previous sequence to match the end of the string. `^hr$` will only match strings that are "hr".